# XCode warns for unreleased objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to make XCode warn for unreleased objects?
It may be useful for classes with lots of objects and I forgot to put [obj release]; in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Analyze tool ("Build and Analyze" in Xcode 3), which does static analysis and points out where you have unreleased objects. More detail here: [Build and Analyze: running the analyzer within Xcode](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a compiler warning because it's valid Objective-C (though *bad* Objective-C), but if you use the static analyzer instead of the compiler, it can often detect cases where an object is leaked. (You still have to use the compiler to run your app, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you change your build settings to let it run everytime you compile your software.

How to turn it on:
Select your project - Build Settings - Build Options - Run static Analyzer [YES]

[image]